# Drawing some objects wireframe in DirectX11

Tags: directx, directx-11, rasterizer-state

I need to draw some objects wireframe and some solid. I assume it is a bad practice to call `RSSetState` for every object.

Probably i can split objects in two groups and draw wireframe group and then solid group. But i'm not sure it is possible because i may have other things to consider.

Maybe i can somehow create index buffer for lines and draw wireframe with lines, but i still need culling to work on these lines, is it possible?

```
rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
...
rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_WIREFRAME;
```

Comment: `But i'm not sure it is possible because i may have other things to consider. ` Have you met such other things right now? if not, don't over design, just try it!

Comment: *"I assume it is a bad practice to call RSSetState for every object"* Maybe your assumption is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but would be time wasting, because if you also want culling, you could enable wireframe with it, so your extra work and time would be wasted.

As stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205071(v=vs.85).aspx):

> In Direct3D 10, device state is grouped into state objects which greatly reduce the cost of state changes.

Although this is for D3D10, it is exactly the same in D3D11 (D3D11 was partly optimized). The best would be to slit your objects in to two groups, as you stated, or try to do as many groups as possible as you stated it's maybe not possible.

Side note: You probably also set your vertex buffer, index buffer and primitive topology list (at least it's what I do) each frame, so setting the `RSSetState` is basically the same thing!